# EF.Functions.Like() for an array of string

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to filter the `IQueryable<T>` with the help of `EF.Functions.Like()` method, which accepts a string parameter, to make use of array of strings. Also, I want this filter to be applied on an `IQueryable` and not on a List.

```cs
var configurations = _dbContext.Configurations
    .Include(x => x.ChildTable)
    .Where(x => x.Id == Id);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Filter))
{
    configurations = configurations.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(string.Join(", ", x.ChildTable.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()), '%' + request.Filter + '%'));
}
```

In the above code, Configuration has a one-many relationship with the `ChildTable`. Meaning, each configuration will have a more than one `ChildTable` entries related. So, with that given, `x.ChildTable.Select(x => x.Name)` is of type `IEnumerable<string>`. And, I want to filter the Configuration records whose `ChildTable.Name` entries is like the given `request.Filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var configurations = _dbContext.Configurations
    .Include(x => x.ChildTable)
    .Where(x => x.Id == Id);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Filter))
{
    configurations = configurations
        .Where(x => x.ChildTable.Any(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.Name, '%' + request.Filter + '%')));
}
```